# ibm navigator close search tab

Tags: search, ibm-content-navigator

I'm developing custom action to open search template with specified values
the action working fine for the first time but when trigger the action again nothing happen, so i need to close the search tab before retrieving Search Template again with the new values.
i tried this code :

`var SearchTabContainer = dijit.byId("ecm_widget_search_SearchTabContainer_0");
            if(SearchTabContainer){
                SearchTabContainer.closeTab({
                    tabType: "search",
                    name:"ZH&P Document Search",
                    title:"ZH&P Document Search",
                    repository: repository,
                    selected: true,
                    closable: true
                }, false);
        }`

but still not working, can anyone mention the correct arguments for "closeTab" function ?

Comment: Does [this](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.1.0/com.ibm.developingeuc.doc/doc/JavaScriptdoc/symbols/ecm.widget.SearchTabContainer.html) help?

Comment: i'm trying to use "closeTab" function, but i need to know whats the correct parameters of "kwargs" in closeTab(kwArgs, noConfirmDialog)